# Online shop that accepts credit cards and PayPal

Tags: web-apps, cms, self-hosted, ecommerce

I am an entry level web developer who is comfortable with Joomla and WordPress. I am trying to build an online shop on my own linux server. There are way too many options out there than I am able to try them out and decide which is best for me.

The size of the online shop will be small to medium, it should be able to accept credit cards and PayPal as payment methods. About features other than basic buy-and-sell process, I havn't decided yet, the only must-have thing is CMS feature. Also custom field is a plus, warehouse management is out of my radar for now.  http://newyorkliquorgiftshop.com is a fair example.

I have tried [Virtue Mart 3](https://virtuemart.net/). It disappoints me as its previous versions did, mainly because of the difficulty to use - too many technical issues are brought up while I am just trying to do basic configuration, and even its default front page has some CSS issues that cause layout problem.

If the solution is really good, I don't mind paying no more than $100, monthly subscription is a no-no, so things like Shopify or Volusion are ruled out.

Two options I am looking at are [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/) and [HikaShop](http://www.hikashop.com/) (Joomla ext.). What is worth trying out?

Comment: Have you looked at WooCommerce?

Comment: Avoid opencart, it's full of security problems (including the main developer who also has a very poor attitude and is constantly publicly cutting developers down then closing issues unresolved who report the problems). As for Joomla, generally don't use it. For a workframe, look towards Laravel or Symfony components. As for @Daniel suggestion above, if you don't want to create it yourself, Woocommerce will be your best option. Be sure to check additional plugins yourself carefully and be advised some functionality will / (or rather) can cost.

Comment: You probably need to do some more planning before evaluating potential solutions. For example, in addition to payment methods, you'll also need to decide what delivery methods are needed, what tax support is needed, are invoices needed and so on. I personally prefer Joomla and EShop which ticks all the boxes for me (including Australian GST and Australia Post delivery method), is easy to set up and is great value for money.